# Change the Cursor to Hourglass even when out of focus

Tags: c#

can somebody help me?
I am trying to Change the Cursor to the Hourglass.
I know that I can do this.Cursor but it just changes the Cursor of the form / the button.
Soooo, how can I change the Cursor to the HourGlass even out of focus.
Pleas help me.

Comment: are you using windows forms? and sould it be changed only if you are on this button?(hover)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you encountered any errors? Please edit your post with any relevant code.